# QueryString too long error when passing MVC model content via DXScript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I am having Querystring too long error when passing MVC model content via DXScript.
I am using DevExpress 16.1 and Devexpress' model binder. 
I tried to tune RequestQueryString  settings in the project's web.config file, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind tha it is a good practice to avoid long query strings. The default length value of maximum query string is 2048 bytes. IIS throws error for any query string in the url exceeding this limit.

You may try to use encrypt data in the query string. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25719/Query-string-encryption-for-ASP-NET